# Mongodb query equivalent of the following SQL query

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongo-collection, mongo-cxx-driver

I have a table as UserData which has strucure like

```
 id category    value
 1  AR          100
 2  WT          90
 3  WT          12
 4  AR          1000
 5  AR          2005
 6  WT          122
 7  BP          112
 8  BP          18
```

now  I want to select all rows which has maximum  value in the indiviual category. so my result set should be.

```
id  category    value   
5   AR          2005    
6   WT          122     
7   BP          112
```

I want to have this in MongoDB  query.

It`s sql equivalent is this one

```
     select id,category,value from
        (select id,
                category,
                value,
                max(value)
        over (partition by category) result
        from   UserData ) a 
       where a.result=a.value order by a.id
```

I want to know that How can I produce same result in the MongoDB query

Comment: Check out the [MongoDB .NET Drive Docs](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.2/)

Comment: Search term ["mongodb max value"](https://www.google.com/search?q=mongodb+max+value&ie=utf-8) All top results are relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Use aggregation

```
db.UserData.aggregate({$group:{_id:"$category", "maxValue":{$max:"$value"}}});
```